# XML header in SOAP (JBoss)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, jboss

I'm using JBoss 5.1GA, by default soap sent without xml header:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Body>
    ....
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

but I need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Body>
    ....
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

My soap handler:

```
public class XmlSOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(XmlSOAPHandler.class);

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        Boolean isOutbound = 
                (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (isOutbound) {
            SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
            try {
                soapMsg.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                soapMsg.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");
            } catch (SOAPException e) {
                LOG.error("Exception while setting properties");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Handler attached to web service, and soap messages successfully intercepted, but no xml header is not added. What I doing wrong?